# How do I add a combo box to a DataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3, combobox

I want to add a ComboBox to a DataGrid. So far, the only way I've found to do it is like this:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Header" dataField="src" >
<mx:itemRenderer>
<mx:Component>
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{data.srcChoices}" />
</mx:Component>                                             
</mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

The problem is the initial value of the ComboBox isn't set correctly. If I hard code the choices, then the initial value is set correctly. I can't hard code the choices. Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the initial value to be set based on a variable from the value object, and not a magic number.  To do this, you have to do something like this:

```
selectedIndex="{(outerDocument as WorkHist).findItemIndexOccupation(data.Occupation)}" dataProvider="{outerDocument.occData}"
```

where WorkHist is the Canvas, or whatever component the DG is living in.

```
public function findItemIndexOccupation(data:String):int {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < occData.length; i++) {
        if (occData.getItemAt(i).POSITION == data) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can add content to the combobox and set the "selectedItem" value to whatever the proper index is.

```
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{data.srcChoices}" selectedindex="2" />
```

2) You can give your combobox an ID and then select the item with ID.selectedIndex in a script

```
ID.selectedIndex = 2;
```